# Can not create Java package in correct folder (Netbeans 1.1.8) . This is preventing me from passing an assignment

Tags: java, netbeans, package

I am currently doing a free Java course online called MOOC made by the University of Helenski. One challenge requires us to create new packages and such. The main issue I was having was that my code would not compile because it would refuse to acknowledge the Main class I created for it, even after I manually selected it (see one of the screenshots below).

I have found solutions of this challenge online and all the packages are created in a folder called "Source Packages" . The problem I am having is that every-time I create a new package, it automatically shows up in the "Test packages" folder.

I tried looking online to see how I can create a "Source Packages" folder on Netbean but I have not been successful in finding out how to go about this because this challenge is not letting me create a "Source Packages" folder. I am fairly new with Java and any help is appreciated. Thank you.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have just created the wrong project type. Is it possible that this is a TMC project and not a normal Java-Application? Then it would make sense, that there are only test-packages available.

Comment: How can I go about to creating the correct project type ? We don't actually create the projects, the projects are downloaded through TMC. I am stuck here on what to do. Here is the solution for the challenge, notice there is a seperate project folder labeled src/mooc: https://github.com/wei-tc/Helsinki-MOOC-OO-Java-Part-II/tree/master/week9-week9_17.FirstPackages

Comment: and it does not work if you create these folders manually? try switching to the "Files"-Tab in NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

If this folder is missing, you can create it like this:

**1.) Create a new folder:** 
Right-klick on your project in projectexplorer -> new -> other:
New-File-Window opens: on the left list klick "other", on the right list klick "folder", then klick next.
Now you can choose Foldername and Location. Click finish and the new folder is created.
2.) **Set the new created folder as new source:**
Right-klick on your project, select "properties", then on the opening "Project-Properties" Window in the list on the left side klick "sources", then on the right lower list you can add the created folder (klick add...)
Finally click ok and the folder should appear in your Menu.